# Can't install OpenGL on MacOS10.14

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl

I've tried many ways to install OpenGL, using homebrew to install glfw and glew:

$ brew install glew glfw3

Or compile through source code:

$ cd glfw && cmake . && make && sudo make install
$ cd glew && make && sudo make install

Xcode is used to create the project. Opengl.framework, glut.framework, libglfw3. A and libglew. A are all added to the project. The header file path is / usr / local / include, and the library path is / usr / local / lib. Main.cpp source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
void Render(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    {
        glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
        glVertex2f(0, .5);
        glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);
        glVertex2f(-.5,-.5);
        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glVertex2f(.5, -.5);
    }
    glEnd();
}
int main(void) {
    GLFWwindow* win;
    if(!glfwInit()){
        return -1;
    }
    win = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "OpenGL Base Project", NULL, NULL);
    if(!win)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(!glewInit())
    {
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(win);
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(win)){
        Render();
        glfwSwapBuffers(win);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    return 0;
}
```

Error in compilation:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
... (many can't find errors)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: From what i know OpenGL is deprecated on Mac from 10.14 onwards. It might still run but you should look into that, maybe that's what is causing your issue.

Comment: You can not install OpenGL. [OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php) is a specification. The interface is provided by the graphics driver. [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) is an OpenGL wrangler (adapter) and [GLFW](https://www.glfw.org/index.html) is  a simple API for creating windows.